# Best practices for Initialization part of a WCF service

Tags: wcf

I have a WCF service with a defined workflow.
There is a process followed in my company for all the development which involves:

1. Having a config file for the application
2. Initializing the log file path

I have read that a static constructor in the service class will do this but is it the correct way of doing things?

The service is hosted in a Windows service and the configuration is like so for the service class:

```
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single, ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Single)]
```

...and in the app.config, the throttling is set like so:

```
<serviceThrottling maxConcurrentCalls="1" maxConcurrentSessions="5" maxConcurrentInstances="5" />
```

How do I write the initialization so that it executes only on startup that will work for every option in `InstanceContextMode`?

What are the best practices to do 1 and 2 for a WCF service?

Reading the config file and initializing the log file should happen once; that code is not expected to execute for each request unless the service is restarted.

Comment: For the throttling I don't think you have a lot of control over how many times the config file is read - it will depend on the particular `InstanceContextMode` to a great deal, especially if it's set to `PerCall` (though I could be wrong) - you may have to look at the WCF extension points (service behavior specifically in your case) to override default runtime behavior.  You could cache the log file path however (using MemoryCache if your on .NET 4.0 or later).

Comment: Hi @Tim, thanks for your response. Since the WCF service will be hosted as a windows service I have decided to put the startup code in the OnStart method. The initial testing is positive and I guess this will work for this kind of problem. Regards.